# Adaptive step size Runge Kutta: getting a specific value

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization, runge-kutta-methods

A system of differential equations can be solved using a numerical integrator with adaptive stepsize $ h$, e.g. [Runge Kutta Fehlberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta%E2%80%93Fehlberg_method)

Now suppose I want to integrate a set of differential equations $\{\dot{x}, \dot{y}, \dot{z} \}$ numerically (e.g. the 3D trajectory of some particle). Each differential equation uses the same adaptive stepsize $h$.

I want to evaluate $x,y$ at some specific target value of $z = z_t$

Now, due to the adaptive stepsize, it is unlikely that $z$ will ever be exactly $z_t$. That is to say, I might get for integration step $n$ and step $n+1$, $z_n=z_t + \epsilon$, $z_{n+1}=z_t - \delta$ for small values $\epsilon, \delta$

Obviously, by setting a more strict tolerance on the integrator, I can get close to $z_t$, but this would be at the expense of speed.

Given that I know *a priori* that I want to evaluate $x,y$ at $z=z_t$, is there a method which permits both an adaptive stepsize, and an exact $z=z_t$ result?

Thanks

Comment: See for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/48892663/3088138 where zero-crossings of an oscillatory process are computed. The last attempt uses Newton's method for finding the best `t`. Note that `odeint` uses `lsoda` which uses adaptive step sizes.

Comment: Why do you want to control the position of the last step indirectly via the tolerances and not directly by cutting it to the desired length?

Comment: @LutzL Thanks for your reply. Can you explain what you mean by 'cutting it to the desired length'?

Comment: something like `if t+1.01*dt > tf then dt = tf-t`. The factor `1.01` is to avoid/preempt to cut to a ridiculously small step.

Answer (score -1):

Once you choose a method, it has an order which approximates how the error depends on stepsize.  The popular fourth order Runge-Kutta has an error that scales as $h^4$.  You can get an approximation to the accuracy by doing your step once as a full step and once as two half steps.  You would expect the error to be reduced by a factor $16$ so the difference between them is about $15$ times the error of the two step approach.  You can use this to update your stepsize.  There is a discussion in chapter 17.2 of [Numerical Recipes](http://numerical.recipes/) and probably in many other numerical analysis texts.

Comment: The question was IMO not about implementing the adaptive step size, but how to implement what is sometimes called "events" on top of an adaptive scheme.